# Change "gaming" to "arqade" in footer

Tags: feature-request, footer, site-name

The site https://gaming.stackexchange.com/ was indeed named "Gaming" in the beginning but [changed to "Arqade"](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4821/7652) about 8 months ago.

There is even domain http://www.arqade.com (which currently redirects to  http://gaming.stackexchange.com)

I can't see any reason to leave the old name in the footer, note that it's "Arqade" in the [list of all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The new footer will be using site names.

Arqade and Mi Yodeya it is, and hovering over the name gives you a description.

Update:

We will add some overrides for specific sites, so it will be clearer what topic they belong to - so it will be "Arqade (gaming)" and "Mi Yodeya (Judaism)" and such.

Comment: Cheers, so this is status-completed then, in spite of the disagreement of many people here. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That's how SO works: we argue and build consensus, and then the developers ignore that and do whatever they want.

Comment: @Nicol did you miss the "We will add some overrides for specific sites"? They didn't ignore, without the arguments here they wouldn't be adding those overrides.

Answer (score 14):

No, please don't change it. The links in the footer are not site names - they are **topics**.

**Topics** are meaningful to everyone: regulars, brand new visitors, search engines.

**Site names** are only meaningful to regulars. And any regular who wanted Arqade, would know they wanted the gaming site anyway.

Comment: This is a good point. I wouldn't know what Arqade meant. I just think it's a spelling mistake on first glance.

Comment: Not sure I agree, but this might explain other choices made in the footer as ben described in his answer.

Comment: So "stackoverflow.com", "serverfault.com" and "superuser.com" are topics then? *[NOTE: I'm not being totally serious here]*

Comment: I really think the _.com_ should be removed @Chris... it's kinda pointless. It could easily by "stack overflow", "server fault" and "super user".

Answer (score 10):

By the same rationale the following changes should also be made:

- Cooking to Seasoned Advice
- Apple to Ask Different
- Stats to Cross Validated
- Judaism to Mi Yodeya

Having said that I'm in two minds about this. On the All Sites page you can click on a site and it explains what the site is about. In the footer this doesn't happen. A descriptive single word in the footer that adequately explains what the site is about may be preferable to the brand of the site itself, which is available once you navigate there anyway.

Comment: Maybe I'm going blind but is Mi Yodeya missing as well?

Comment: Ben: "Judaism".

Comment: I agree that the footer should be somewhat synchronized with the "all sites" list, but good point that it should be kept short. However "gaming" is no better than "arqade" in my opinion.

Comment: Cheers @Matt, I am going blind!

Comment: Hm, interestingly I note that Superuser/stackoverflow/Server Fault are all listed as "X.com", probably since they're not topic names. I'd rather keep the topic names for that list.